# Create Custom Override method issue

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have created the class like below. But Override method is not called. Is anything I missed? Otherwise i need to add any key word(`like Virtual`) to use as Override?

**MyWebView.java**

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;    

import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyWebView extends WebView 
{
    WebView localView;
    static Context localcontext;
    A aclass;

    public MyWebView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);     
        localcontext=context;
    }

    public LinearLayout init()
    {
        LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(localcontext);
        localView=new WebView(localcontext);
        localView.setWebViewClient(new MyClient());
        aclass=new A();
        layout.addView(localView);
        return layout;
    }

    class MyClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            aclass.startMyMethod();
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }

}
```

**A.java**

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.app.Activity;

public class A extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyWebView view=new MyWebView(this);
        LinearLayout layout = view.init();
        view.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
        setContentView(layout);
     }

    public void startMyMethod() 
    {       
        System.out.println("ParentMethod");
    }
}
```

**B.java(MainActivity)**

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }

    @Override
    public void startMyMethod() {
        System.out.println("ChildMethod");
        super.startMyMethod();
    }

}
```

> Note: class B is client side class. others two in jar file.  how can i
>   use new B() inside jar file(library source). name B may be changed. **If parent method is overridden, then parent content should not be executed**

Comment: How did you call it and how do you know it is not called ?

Comment: Are you calling `startMyMethod` on an intance of `B`?

Comment: please put a `System.out.println` in both methods and see if they gets called. They must be.

Comment: Given `B.startMyMethod();` just calls its parent, how can you tell the difference?

Comment: @Nishant: I have tried to print like you said, but getting Parent method called

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Dont want to create instance of ParentClass.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar: I have called that startMyMethod inside A class later

Comment: @Ponmalar Can you provide an example of code which demonstrates your problem, because the code works as expected when I run it?

Comment: @Ponmalar And how do I run that? ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I gave an example, but that meants, startMyMethod will be called in some situations, not in starting stage

Comment: You gave an example which I cannot compile, let alone run. It suggests to me that something is happening which is not understood in code not provided because you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the method in Class B should execute, you should call that method in an object of Class B.

Comment: See the edited code, you can run it easily

Comment: You are calling the method in Class A only, `aclass=new A();` and `aclass.startMyMethod();` Try `aclass=new B();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have any keyword like `virtual`, by default all java non-static methods are virtual. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#Java.

@Override annotation is used to instruct compiler that you are overriding super class method. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

```
A a =new A();
a.startMyMethod(); // calls A.startMyMethod()

A b = new B(); // Object reference of type A and Object of B
a.startMyMethod(); // calls B.startMyMethod()
```

Comment: This code will fail due to a being redeclared - that's why I edited it. :)

Comment: Dont want to create instance of ParentClass. want to use Parentclass method as Overrides

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you create an instance of ClassB and call the overridden method like below:

```
ClassB b = new ClassB();
b.strartMyMehtod();
```

Put some prints inside the ClassB method before the call to the parent to see the difference.

```
class A
{
     public void startMyMethod()
     {
         System.out.println("A.startMyMethod() called");
     }
 }    

class B extends A
 {
    @Override
     public void startMyMethod() {
         System.out.println("B.startMyMethod() called");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.startMyMethod();
     }
 }
```

Comment: You have to ship the jar you want to use on the client side to the client. Otherwise the client code will not compile.

Comment: see, please understand my concept, i can give the jar to customer. but customer may have class x instead of B. ok.

Answer (score 1):

In your init() method of `MyWebView.java` you initialize variable 
`aclass` variable as `aclass=new A();`

In `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method, you call

```
aclass.startMyMethod();
```

**Since A is parent class, it will only called startMyMethod() of A class.**

In order to get advantage of inheritance and override, you can initialize
`aclass` variable `as aclass=new B();` This will call startMyMethod() of B class and then call startMyMethod() of A class because of using `super.startMyMethod();`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html said that

> **@Override**—the @Override annotation informs the compiler that the
>   element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass
>   (overriding methods will be discussed in the the lesson titled
>   "Interfaces and Inheritance").

Not for program execution sequence. I hope it may be your want.

Comment: See, If the client is extends A Class, they can use  A class public method as Overrides.

Comment: if a child class extends a parent class, child class possess both properties and methods of parent class. So child class B can even use startMyMethod() without overriding in its own class.

Comment: Thanks for the link. but it is called when the Activity started, but it should be called in some situation only.

Comment: B is user class, i could not use new B() in my code. class name B may change.